# How a man can go after his desire of research without following coaching institutes for qualifying competitive exams?

Tags: research-undergraduate, exams

The era in which we live is full of competition, I want to know why competitive exams have taken such an important status? I have read about Mr. Daniel Kane, Mr. Terrence Tao etc. they are so famous not because of their research and contributions to Mathematics but because they cleared Olympiads at young age and selected for renowned institutes at young age. So, people like me, who are not child prodigy but have a devastating desire to do something in Mathematics, are usually left out and get depressed.
Next come to those coaching institutes who prepare students for Competitive Exams, JEE can explain it better than anything. Coaching institutes in India prepare students for JEE by making them work irrelevantly. They somehow crack the questions which IIT JEE going to give and they teach them all possible questions, thus creating unnecessary pressure. Consequently, paper-setters try even harder to make the exam as tough as possible, so as you can see we the people get thrashed out for no cause.
So, I want to know how can people like me get into higher society of Science , is it necessary for us to qualify some well known examination? Is it necessary to publish some papers which do not worth even reviewing? How can we go on after our desire and accomplish it?
To provide more illustration I'm sharing a link https://youtu.be/HcZtBr5XlCQ.
If I want to do research in my preferred field, is it necessary for me to follow the tricks and nonsensical teachings of coaching institutes to clear comptetitions and then get into reputed University or institute and give a rebirth to my desire which was exterminated due to travelling to get here?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95510/discussion-on-question-by-adesh-mishra-how-a-man-can-go-after-his-desire-of-rese).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this question sounds like a rant indeed, so I hope I will be forgiven to give a quick answer based on general knowledge rather than specific research works you can dig deeper.

Many countries during certain development phases indeed go through a stage characterized by very high competition and tough exams that often define the fate of applicants. Say, in Japan it was known as "exam hell", which is probably [over now](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2009/01/20/reference/exam-hell-now-not-so-hot/).

I believe this stage coincides with (a) growing demand for skilled workforce and (b) lack of educational institutions able to provide sufficient training. Putting it simply, there are more people willing to pursue higher education, but there are not enough universities ranked high among employers. Eventually the situation should come to a better balance, but it might take years if not decades.

The core issue for people like you, of course, is what to do about it right now. One answer is already mentioned here -- get your education elsewhere, not all countries are like that. Another answer is to find an institution that is not that competitive but still provides reasonably good education.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this article might help?

https://www.nytimes.com/2011/10/14/world/asia/squeezed-out-in-india-students-turn-to-united-states.html

It says that acceptance rates at top Indian universities for science and engineering are as low as 2%. That's ridiculously low for undergraduate admissions. If you want to pursue higher education but the competition is too stiff in India, maybe looking outside India could be an option.

Comment: Competition  is not stiff, students from class 6 th start coaching for one particular exam and finally they become able to do better because they know what’s gonna come. But to tell the truth they get exhausted and can’t use themselves anymore to do something worth mentioning and we people who have desire to do are denied good education.

Comment: By stiff I mean it's fierce. You could go and study in a country where it's easier to be admitted to a good undergraduate programme.